# Xpath substring-before gets only one element

Tags: xml, xpath, substring

```
<row transactionDateTime="2012-06-04 02:42:44" transactionID="2519826732" quantity="5000" typeName="Caldari Navy Mjolnir Rocket" typeID="27321" price="988.72" clientID="92026367" clientName="N Clover" stationID="60003760" stationName="Jita IV - Moon 4 - Caldari Navy Assembly Plant" transactionType="buy" transactionFor="personal" journalTransactionID="5956192510"/>
```

Hello,

Above is a sample of the XML file I am trying to extract data from. The piece of data I want to extract is;

```
transactionDateTime="2012-06-04"
```

Now - I am having no problems getting this with the following Xpath query;

```
substring-before(//row[@transactionfor='personal']/attribute::transactiondatetime, ' ')
```

This gets me exactly what I want - "2012-06-04", but it only gets me one element! If I drop the substring-before it will get me all elements, but include the time.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3):

```
substring-before(//row[@transactionfor='personal']/attribute::transactiondatetime, ' ')
```

In XPath 1.0 if a node-set is passed as argument where a single value (string) is expected, the first node in the node-set is used as the argument. The rule is to apply the function **[`string()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string)** to the passed node-set and by definition `string($nodeset)` is the same as `string($node-set[1])`.

In XPath 2.0 the above expression should cause an error.

**It isn't possible with a single XPath expression to produce the results of a function that is applied to all selected nodes, when the number of nodes is greater than 1**.

Therefore, each selected node must be processed in a second step (probably in a loop specified in the programming language that is hosting XPath).

**In XPath 2.0 it is possible to use a function call as the last location step of an expression**.

Thus it is possible to produce a sequence of *all* wanted strings with this XPath 2.0 expression:

```
//row[@transactionfor='personal']
           /attribute::transactiondatetime
                           /substring-before(., ' ')
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre,

I am really starting to think this is an issue with Google Spreadsheets. I used the expression you gave, but came up with the following error:   

error: The xPath query given could not be evaluated. Please check the syntax of the query: //row[@transactionfor='personal']/attribute::transactiondatetime/substring-before(.,' ')  

As you can see it was essentially a copy/paste, but it still did not work. I can see your massive reputation and very solid description of the problem, so my assumption is you have the correct syntax, but Google Spreadsheets is having some problems.

Comment: Also, the top expression; 
   
substring-before(//row[@transactionfor='personal']/attribute::transactiondatetime, ' ')  

Did not given an error, but returned one value. I believe you said it would cause an error since I am telling it to "produce results of a function that is applied to all selected nodes, when the number of nodes is greater than 1."  
  
But, it does not given an error. It simply returns one value and does nothing for the rest.

Comment: Also, I am sorry about the lack of formatting in my posts. I am not sure why, but I cannot for the life of me get the break line to work.

Comment: @Flynn1179: ????? I don't understand anything at all from your last comment -- could you, please, elaborate?

Comment: @Flynn1179: Oh, I see ... :) Even in this case the statement is true :) Congrats, you are the only one who noticed this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because the first argument of `substring-before()` is a string and you're passing it the `transactionDateTime` attributes of all the rows.

Try this instead:

```
//row[@transactionFor='personal']/substring-before(@transactionDateTime,' ')
```

Comment: Tried a copy/paste, but I got an error that the xPath query could not be completed.. please check the syntax and try again. I also tried; //row/substring-before([@transactionfor='personal']/attribute::transactiondatetime, ' ')

Comment: @user1438413 - It works fine for me in oXygen. What processor are you using? Try this instead: `//row/@transactionDateTime/substring-before(.,' ')`

Comment: I am on a school computer, but I am using this in google spreadsheets, so that should be irrelevant. It is still not able to work with the changes - same error.

Comment: It might be a spreadsheets error. I tried creating another importXML function and was given an error that I need to check the file - which is accurate. Going home now, will be back!

Comment: Hey again, still seems to not be working and it is giving me a syntax error on the ImportXML function.

Comment: If you are still around DevNull, I would be happy to give you access to my spreadsheet to see what you can figure out. I have been trying different variations of the above to see what I can get working, but I have not gotten anywhere. The original formula to get all of the dates + times works as does the original string-before to get just the first date.

Comment: @user1438413 - I'd be happy to take a look at your spreadsheet. My email is in my profile.

Comment: The solution given by DevNull is correct for XPath 2.0 but not for XPath 1.0.