# XPATH that does extract style background color RGB value?

Tags: xpath, extract

Can someone tell me an XPATH that does extract background color RGB values, or whole style, then I will remove unneeded data using Excel find/replace.

Been able to extract car color names using XPATH //div[@class='colorName']

```
<div class="colours" style="background-color: #040404; height: 30px; width: 130px; margin: 7px"></div>
<div class="colorName">Obsidian Black</div>
```

Source page: http://www.carwale.com/mercedesbenz-cars/e-class/e63amg-3049/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the combination of [`substring-after()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-after) and [`substring-before()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-before):

```
substring-before(substring-after(//div[@class="colours"]/@style, "background-color: "), ";")
```

Works for me in the chrome console:

```
> $x('substring-before(substring-after(//div[@class="colours"]/@style, "background-color: "), ";")')
"#040404"
```

Comment: I extract using import.io and here your XPath DOES NOT WORK! in XPath Helper extension for Chrome it does extract only first RGB value. I need to extract RGB values of ALL car colors as does  //div[@class='colorName']

Comment: @Future In understand. Unfortunately, this is the limitation of `substring-before()` and `substring-after()`, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905659/xpath-substring-before-gets-only-one-element. If you can, extract the `@style` values and post-process them separately, not in an XPath. Thanks.

Comment: So how I can extract full style values of class="colours" ?

Comment: @Future just `//div[@class="colours"]/@style` would do that.

Comment: WORKED! Thank you, apparently is a simple XPath but somewhat it did not came in my mind at time.